# Scalar multiples of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices

For orthogonal matrices, I know that $A^TA = AA^T = I$.

But if we have some matrix $AA^T = \lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is an integer scalar, I believe it's still true that $A^TA = AA^T = \lambda I$. Is there an easy way to show this?

Comment: $A$ is square matrix? The accepted answer is incorrect. Please check that $(AA^T)^T=AA^T$ and not $A^TA$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $A$ is invertible and if $ A A^ T = \lambda I$ then $ A ^ {-1}= \frac{1}{\lambda} A^T $ ,
When $ \lambda \neq 0 $ , So $A^T A =  \lambda \  A^{-1} A = \lambda I $. When $ \lambda = 0 $ , $A A^ T = 0 $ implies A is zero matrix because A is orthogonal to itself, So $ A^T A = 0 $.

Comment: thank you, is the tranpose of $\lambda I$=$I \lambda$, and the order doesnt matter? sorry im rusty on the definition here

Comment: Since $\lambda$ is a scalar, it just multiplies all values in the matrix and it's typical to write it before the matrix but it makes no real difference.

Comment: Incorrect. $(AA^T)^T=AA^T$ only

Comment: We cannot talk of inverse of $A$ without knowing that $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: @shubhamjohri so if A is a square matrix, then is $(^)^=^A$?

Comment: No. The identity is $(MN)^T=N^TM^T$.